# Break string into parts that start with character

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have the string `#foo=bar#dude`. How can I break this into an array that contains:

```
[0] = "#foo=bar"
[1] = "#dude"
```

The leading `#` doesn't need to part of the resulting strings.

Comment: Without the # you can use `string.split('#')` .

Comment: @deEr. The first element is empty.

Comment: So shift() off the empty element?

Comment: `string.split('#').splice(1)`. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you can split the string into two different items within an array. Here's an example using JavaScript.

```js
var str = "#foo=bar#dude";
var result = str.split(/(?=#)/);
console.log(result);
```

Here's an explanation of the regular expressions within the split function:

- **(?=#)**: This positive lookahead assertion matches a position
  in the string where the next character is #. With this pattern, you split the string into a separate item within an array each time a *#* character is present.

Comment: Thank you, this is the elegant solution I'm after!